# I am curious about Why usage in the following sentences

Tags: usage

- **Why** Something Instead of Nothing?
- **Why** Something New?
- **Why** Dog in the Wind?
- **why** thing in the back of my throat?
- **Why** everything on zero?

I looked up "Why" in my dictionary, but I could not figure out how it was used.
Please let me know usage of"why"

Comment: Your questions are not clear. None of the phases you give are sentences: they do not contain verbs. You need to explain exactly what you are asking and to give the context.

Comment: The sentences are not grammatically correct, but *why* here seems to mean exactly what it normally means: "What is the reason for ____ ?"

Comment: @ stangdon Oh thank you. If so, is the following sentence also grammatically wrong?  "why the word up in call up a friend?"

Comment: @Lami - That sentence is also not correct because it does not contain a verb.  I think it should be "Why **is** the word..." or "Why **do we say** the word..."

Comment: @stangdon- Thank you very much. I was confused with this sentence in the introduction text of "Richard Spears-Essential Phrasal Verbs Dictionary", but now the question has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "sentences" you quote are so much part of everyday English, that they could be considered idiomatic.

However parts of them, including the main verb (often "is/are*) have been  elided. Hence the argument that they cannot be sentences, "because they do not contain a verb".

***Why (have you bought) something new?***

***Why (is) everything on zero?***

In ***Why the fuss?***, the elision is not as straightforward. What is being said is ***Why (is there) a fuss (being made)?*** But the article has changed from indefinite to definite.